# Gender of "Weisen" in "Harry Potter und der Stein der Weisen"

Tags: translation, english-to-german

The title of the first Harry Potter book is "Harry Potter und der Stein der Weisen". (English: Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone)

I noticed that "Weise" is a noun that declines as an adjective. Does that mean the gender of "Weisen" here is feminine or plural? Why is it not translated as the masculine "des Weisen"?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Die Weisen* is plural here (which means that the gender can't be determined). The expression, which is many centuries older than the Harry Potter series, is a translation of the Latin *lapis philosophorum*, where *philosophorum* is plural as well (in genitive).

An interesting question (but for ELU) is why there is variation between *philosopher's stone* and *philosophers' stone* in English. [Apparently](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Talk%3Aphilosophers%27_stone), the dictionaries vary as well.

Comment: Ja, ich war neugierig, weil der englischen Harry Potter Titel "Philosopher" als ein singuläres Nomen hat. Sowieso, danke!

Comment: "*Die Weisen is plural here*" derived from the context, but definitely not from the wording itself ...

Comment: @alk: I don’t say otherwise, and go on to explain that context in my answer.

Answer (score 5):

It is not possible to derive from

```
Der Stein der Weisen
```

whether

```
der Weisen
```

is genitive, singular, female for

```
the wise woman
```

or genitive, plural for

```
the wise [people]
```

For the latter the gender is indetermined, it could be woman or men or both.